# read a kafka topic with logstash and save in file

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

I have a kafka cluster with three node. I want to read message from a kafka topic with logstash and  save messages in file. I wrote a logstash config to read topic and save in file. but I don't know how to save every 20000 in a file.

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "zk_kafka_1:9092,zk_kafka_2:9092,zk_kafka_3:9092"
    topics => ["test"]
    group_id => "logstash"
    consumer_threads => 8
    auto_offset_reset => "latest"
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    remove_field => ["message"]
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "/data/kafka-files-logstash/%{+YYYY.MM.dd-HH:mm:ss}.log"
    codec => plain { format => "%{[event][original]}" }
  }
}
```

It works correct. but it saves messages with random number. for example: one file is 45000 messages and another is 33000 messages.